# Changes in XIB not working in simulator even with autolayout is disabled

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

I have searched for an hour to solve this. I have tried the answers in stackoverflow but nothing helps. So again i am here to ask this question.

I have a storyboard screen which is to be navigated. It was working fine. Now i have added some `buttons` in this `storyboard screen`. When i am running the application, the added button not showing in simulator.

I have tried the following methods to solve this. But nothing helped.

1. Reinstalling the app in simulator
2. Resetting the simulator
3. Removed the derived data folder from xcode

I used the following code to add the subview.

```
offlineView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"OfflineViewController"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:offlineView animated:YES];
```

Can anyone help me to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how u r loading the xib ? Pls show the code

Comment: Did you clear the derived data?

Comment: ok please post some code so we can check if everything is fine

Comment: you are not adding the xib properly. IS the xib a view controller or just view ?

Comment: If it is a view controller, then adding it to a uiview is not going to work. You should load the xib directly.

Comment: Why u cahnged ur code ? Now u r using storyboard but not xib!!!

Comment: also update ur question too!!!

Comment: have you tried debug view hierarchy?

Comment: Thanks you all for your valuable reply.. The added button alone has autolayout enabled. Now i solved this issue with your help.

Comment: @Mr.T Thank you Mr.T